# replace a dead node in GlusterFS

Tags: replace, server, distributed, glusterfs

I have a question about Gluster.

I have a volume with 4 storage(replica 2):

> storag1:/clusterdata
>
> storage2:/clusterdata
>
> storage3:/clusterdata
>
> storage4:/clusterdata

The IP of storage1 is `192.168.56.101`

The IP of storage2 is `192.168.56.102`.

The name of volume is myVolume. One of these storages has been burned(storage3) and I don't have storage3 any more. I want to replace it with a new storage, for example `myNewStorage`(its IP is `192.168.56.110`).

I would really appreciate if someone could help me how can I replace that dead brick with a new brick. I searched a lot but none of the results of google was useful.

Answer (score 1):

**gluster volume replace-brick VOLNAME BRICK NEW-BRICK commit force.**

Check below guide for more info. You need to also make sure heal is completed after replacing it with new brick.
http://www.gluster.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Gluster_File_System-3.3.0-Administration_Guide-en-US.pdf

Comment: Thank you Nithin. The thing is after replacing, the new server is really slow and get the replicas after around 5 mins!! do you have any idea why is it like this?!

Answer (score 1):

The tricky thing is that I should do the **gluster volume replace-brick VOLNAME BRICK NEW-BRICK commit force** at new sever(myNewStorage).

But this new storage syncs with others and get the replicas very slowly!!!